# Excel 2010 Check Boxes Macro - How to deselect a "Select All" checkbox when another box is deselected

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I have a list of countries and list of scenarios for an excel model. Each list has check boxes with an "All Countries" and "All Scenarios" option which will select all the check boxes related to each. When I click the "All Countries" checkbox, each individual country checkbox is properly selected. Same for the "All Scenarios" checkbox. However, if I unselect a single country/scenario, the All Countries/Scenarios boxes remain checked.

How do I get the "All Countries" and "All Scenarios" checkboxes to deselect when a sub-checkbox is deselected?

Below is the code I have so far.

```
Sub SelectAll_Read()
    Dim CB As CheckBox
    For Each CB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If CB.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("MCB.1").Name And CB.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("MCB.2").Name Then
            If Mid(CB.Name, 5, 1) = "1" Then
                CB.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("MCB.1").Value
            ElseIf Mid(CB.Name, 5, 1) = "2" Then
                CB.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("MCB.2").Value
            End If
        End If
    Next CB
    End Sub

    Sub Mixed_ReadState()
    Dim CB As CheckBox
    Dim i As String

    For Each CB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        i = Mid(CB.Name, 5, 1)
        If CB.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("MCB" & i).Name And CB.Value <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("MCB" & i).Value And ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("MCB" & i).Value <> 2 Then
            ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("MCB" & i).Value = 2
            Exit For
        Else
            ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("MCB" & i).Value = CB.Value
        End If
    Next CB
End Sub
```

Comment: This post of mine might be of interest:http://yoursumbuddy.com/userform-event-handler-class-multiple-controls/

Comment: It's not clear from your code how checkboxes are related/grouped by name.  Maybe you could explain your naming scheme.

Comment: @Tim Williams - I used MCB.1 for my "master checkbox 1" which is the All Countries checkbox. Each individual country is then MCB.1.1, .1.2, .1.3 and so on. The name MCB.2 is used as my All Scenarios. Each individual scenario is MCB.2.1, .2.2, .2.3. I hope this clarifies and thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign this to all of the checkboxes on your sheet then it should handle synchronizing the master<>child states.

```
Sub HandleClick()

    Dim sht As Worksheet, nm As String
    Dim arrA, arrB, masterClicked As Boolean
    Dim c As CheckBox, cb As CheckBox
    Dim mixedChildValues As Boolean

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    nm = Application.Caller
    Set cb = sht.CheckBoxes(nm) 'the clicked checkbox

    arrA = Split(nm, ".") 'split the cb name on "." to give an array
    masterClicked = (UBound(arrA) = 1) '"master" cb clicked?

    mixedChildValues = False

    'loop over all checkboxes on the sheet
    For Each c In sht.CheckBoxes

        'ignore the clicked checkbox
        If c.Name <> nm Then

            arrB = Split(c.Name, ".") 'split the name...

            If arrA(1) = arrB(1) Then 'only consider same "family" of checkboxes

                If masterClicked Then
                    'set all childern to "master" value if master was clicked
                    c.Value = cb.Value
                Else
                    If (UBound(arrB) = 2) Then 'only look at children...
                        If c.Value <> cb.Value Then
                            mixedChildValues = True
                            Exit For 'no need to check further...
                        End If
                    End If 'child checkbox
                End If

            End If 'same family
        End If 'not the clicked checkbox
    Next c

    'child checkbox was clicked - see if the master needs adjusting...
    If Not masterClicked Then
        sht.CheckBoxes(arrA(0) & "." & arrA(1)).Value = IIf(mixedChildValues, -4146, cb.Value)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I've incorporated into my file and it works perfectly. I appreciate the notes as well.